# Read video file with fixed frame rate

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video

I captured a video with my camera and fixed frame rate at 25 fps and tried to read it with OpenCV.

When I read video file with OpenCV, it plays but it plays very fast.
I want my program to play video at 25 fps. How to configure OpenCV to read video file at 25 fps?

**My code:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 4):

I found some solution.
I put a delay time to capture loop. I check delay before captures new image from video file. This is my solution code.
Thanks, everybody.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from time import time as timer
import sys

    video = cv2.VideoCapture('2.avi')
    fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    fps /= 1000
    framerate = timer()
    elapsed = int()
    cv2.namedWindow('ca1', 0)
    while(video.isOpened()):

        start = timer()
        # print(start)
        ret, frame = video.read()

        cv2.imshow('ca1',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

        diff = timer() - start
        while  diff < fps:
            diff = timer() - start

        elapsed += 1
        if elapsed % 5 == 0:
            sys.stdout.write('\r')
            sys.stdout.write('{0:3.3f} FPS'.format(elapsed / (timer() - framerate)))
            sys.stdout.flush()

    video.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Why not just use `waitKey` with the correct delay, rather than the additional busy wait?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by your answer:

```
while(cap.isOpened()):

  ret, frame = cap.read()

  now = time.time()
  frameLimit = 2.0

  #Do your stuff

  timeDiff = time.time() - now
  if (timeDiff < 1.0/(frameLimit)): time.sleep( 1.0/(frameLimit) - timeDiff )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution for this problem:

```
fps = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

while True:
    now = time.time()
    _, frame = vid.read()

    #Do your thing

    timeDiff = time.time() - now
    if (timeDiff < 1.0/(fps)):
        time.sleep(1.0/(fps) - timeDiff)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an existing video file, you can not change its FPS. However when you read the video file, you can change the interval you read between each frame. Here is my solution to read at a fixed frame rate 25 fps. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:/Media/videos/Wildlife.wmv')

# Check if camera opened successfully
if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
    print("Error opening video stream or file")

fps = 25
#if you want to have the FPS according to the video then uncomment this code
#fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

#calculate the interval between frame. 
interval = int(1000/fps) 
print("FPS: ",fps, ", interval: ", interval)
# Read the video
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow('Frame',gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(interval) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    # Break the loop
    else: 
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This solution will give inaccurate fps. Because the fps also depends on the speed of the code in between `cap.read()` and `cv2.waitKey(interval)`. Moreover, the fps will dip down if the system is busy doing other stuff. So, the `interval` needs to be dynamically adjusted every loop.

Answer (score -2):

you can add the required fps in place of 'fps' below

```
cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, fps)
```

Comment: Sorry, I use opencv 3, it not found cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS.

Comment: That has absolutely no effect on reading a video file. (And shouldn't -- the last thing you need is your I/O code to waste time doing nothing).

Comment: it is "cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS", but returning false in my case. it is working but returning false